# Beginner C++, Opencv , wrong header files?

Tags: c++, opencv

I've been trying to follow opencv tutorials and I've come across this issue several times.  It seems that for C language, a lot of the functions have a cv prefix in front of them, and for C++ it's a little simpler

[opencv help page](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html)

For the moment function:
you can see that for C language, it's cvMoment, and for c++ its just Moment.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 c++, and a lot of the c++ functions are underlined, like if I typed in Moment, but the C functions seems to have no errors like cvMoment.

Is this because of my include files?  How would I know which include files to include with each function?

Comment: Post the relevant problematic code in the body of your question, including what you used to include the header.

Answer (score 1):

all opencv functions in c++ are declared within the namespace `cv`. You have two options:

**write `cv::` before each function, variable, etc, for example:**

```
cv::Moment();
cv::Mat matrix;
```

**You use the namespace** :
put on top of your c++ file:

```
using namespace cv;
```

then you don't need to type `cv::` for each method

For more information on namespaces, you can read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/)